# Eclipse IDE - Spring MVC - Status 404 - The Requested resource is not available - RequestMapping issue (Not Maven)

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I am learning Spring MVC web application development and trying to navigate from one jsp file to another using Controller and RequestMapping. The 1st page 'index.jsp' is displayed in the http://localhost:8080/ without any issue.

However, the Controller and RequestMapping methods are not working which is evident as System.out.Println() doesn't prints anything in the console. Hence, while navigating to the next jsp pages, error is being thrown as 'Status 404 - The Requested resource is not available'.

Below are the files in the project. I am using spring 3.0.1, Eclipse IDE 4.7.1a and Tomcat 8.0 server.

**Project Structure**

```
--springMvcWeb
    --Java Resources
        --src
            --springMvcWeb 
                --HelloController.java
    --WebContent
        --META-INF
        --WEB-INF
            --jsp
                --final.jsp
                --viewPage.jsp
            --lib
                --dispatcher-servlet.xml
                --web.xml
            --index.jsp
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>
    
    <!--  The below servlet should match the dispatcher-servlet.xml file -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Provide support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="springMvcWeb" />

    <!--Provide support for conversion, formatting and validation-->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    
    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package springMvcWeb;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")  
    public String redirect()  
    {  
        System.out.println("about to display viewpage.jsp");
        return "viewPage";  
    }     
    @RequestMapping("/helloagain")  
    public String display()  
    {  
        System.out.println("about to display final.jsp");
        return "final";  
    }  
}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>  
<body>  
<a href="hello">Click here...</a>  
</body>  
</html>
```

**viewPage.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>  
<body>  
<a href="helloagain">Click viewPage</a>  
</body>  
</html>
```

**final.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>  
<body>  
<p>Welcome to Spring MVC Tutorial</p>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Error page : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixS8G.jpg

Comment: Can you include your pom.xml? Or link the tutorial that you're using as base.

Comment: It is not a Maven project.

I follow https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-tutorial

Comment: Nobody uses JSP anymore.  I'd avoid them.  404 means the URL is incorrect.  Figure out how and fix it.

Comment: I have followed the second part which corresponds to your question https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-multiple-view-page-example and I've navigated through the three pages with no problem. I had minor problems deploying the app to the internal Tomcat. I think that your problem may be there. Check possible errors in the Eclipse console

Comment: What is the problem you faced in deploying.. Will it help to debug my issue. Did you use the pom.xml file? and did you develop it as a maven project?

Comment: Yes, I have used maven. You need maven to generate a war file to deploy the application to the server. How have you done such deployment? Also, use the @ to address someone here at the beginning of the comment :-)

Comment: @RubioRic I didn't use maven in the project. Instead I added the jar files in Java Resources > Libraries >Referenced Libraries. Then cleaned, built and ran the project in the tomcat.

Is it mandatory to use maven.. ? adding the dependent jar files in the reference lib and then building the project doesn't work? I followed the first part of the tutorial(https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-tutorial) in that manner and it worked.

Comment: Check in Project Properties > Deployment Assembly if the folder where you have copied the dependencies is present. If such folder is not there, include it and try again.

Comment: @RubioRic after adding it, the jar files are present in the war file.

however the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `return "viewpage";`  in your home controller but in your project structure image, it's viewPage. So I think you should put the same file name as in your project in your return too as it is case sensitive.

Comment: It was a typo only in my question, but in the original Eclipse IDE they are matching already. Corrected the typo in the question.

Comment: can you update your question with your full error message?

Comment: Added to the question.

Comment: In your console You are getting some output when you got an error message can you share those error messages.

Comment: The console is empty

Comment: @Joohay If you use Eclipse, normally for testing purposes and simple samples, you can deploy your web apps in an internal Tomcat. If such case, when the Tomcat server is started, the console shows the different elements being deployed and instantiated. If you try to access a non-available URL, the console shows an error.

Comment: @Joohay If you're using an "external" Tomcat, you need to locate the server main log file in your file system. It will show you the above mentioned information

Comment: @RubioRic I am running the application in my local server. I only got the logs of server startup in the console. After which when I am clicking the links in jsp files or when the 1st jsp page is refreshed/reloaded I didn't get any logs. May be I have to integrate log4j for the same.. I am not sure.

Comment: @Joohay Update your post with the contents of your war file. Probably you're not including the required jar files. That was the problem I faced because Eclipse was not including them on generating the war. This class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet was not been found by Tomcat.